# groovy script list contains string value

Tags: string, groovy, compare, jira

ı have a groovy script which checks values from fields on screen in a list of values , if they exist.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser;
import java.lang.Object

def groupManager = ComponentAccessor.getGroupManager();
def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();
def eManagerCF = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Ek Manager")
def dedManagerCF = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Ded Manager")
def depManagerCF = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Dep Manager ")

String eManager = issue.getCustomFieldValue(eManagerCF)
String dedManager = issue.getCustomFieldValue(dedManagerCF)
String depManager = issue.getCustomFieldValue(depManagerCF)

if (eManager) {
 eManager = eManager.trim()
}

if (dedManager) {
 dedManager = dedManager.trim()
}

if (depManager) {
 depManager = depManager.trim()
}

cfValues['2. Onay'] ? .value == null && cfValues['1.Adim '] ? .value != "Helpdesk" && cfValues['1. Onay '] ? .value == "Ilgili Yönetici " &&
 (!groupManager.getUsersInGroup('ITSM Onaya Gitmeyecek Personeller ').contains(eManager) ||
  !groupManager.getUserNamesInGroup('ITSM Onaya Gitmeyecek Personeller ').contains(dedManager) ||
  !groupManager.getUsersInGroup('ITSM Onaya Gitmeyecek Personeller ').contains(depManager))
```

**So my problem is:**
 String dedManager=  issue.getCustomFieldValue(dedManagerCF) 
 returns aaa.bbb@xx.com

groupManager.getUsersInGroup('ITSM Onaya Gitmeyecek Personeller) 
returns list with usernames like Aaa.Bbb@xx.com

so the method
 groupManager.getUsersInGroup('ITSM Onaya Gitmeyecek Personeller').contains(depManager))  returns always false

Can you please help?

Answer (score 7):

to simplify your question: how to find a string value in a list ignoring case.

```
def str = 'Aaa.Bbb@xx.com'
def list = ['xxx.yyy@zz.com','aaa.bbb@xx.com']

if( list.find{e-> e.equalsIgnoreCase(str)} ){
    println "found"
}
```

or if you sure that list always contains lowercase items just convert the string to lowercase before applying `contains`

```
def str = 'Aaa.Bbb@xx.com'
def list = ['xxx.yyy@zz.com','aaa.bbb@xx.com']

str = str.toLowerCase()
if( str in list ){
    println "found"
}
```